# How to press down-arrow key of a context menu in Robot Framework

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I need to move the arrow keys to down of a context menu using Robot Framework.How to solve this.Please help me how to solve this.

[image]

Comment: please share what you tried (with some code) and show us the error/problems you encounter.

Answer (score 0):

The full list of the codes can be found in Selenium's [source documentation](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/common/keys.py).

For down arrow you need to use - \ue015,
complete list can be foud here in the documentaion [selenium.webdriver.common.keys](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.keys.html)

```
press key   XPATH_OF_ELEMENT    \ue015
```